# gamecenter on landscape shows partially

Tags: game-center, landscape

Guys can you help me with these? whats wrong here? Gamecenter window wont come all the way.

My app runs always on landscape. It works fine but the effin gamecenter will only show partially. I have no rotation problems and I dont care that the gamecenter loggin shows in portrait. I just want to show the leaderboard. Halp

Heres a picture of my problem:

http://i41.tinypic.com/raount.jpg

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed it. I was using 
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:tempVC.view]; to add the gamecenter views. Changed that to:

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[appDelegate.window addSubview:tempVC.view];